# CUPS timeout for change status to error

Tags: debian, cups

I recently installed CUPS 1.5.3 on my Debian Squeeze server. I don't think it's relevant but I think the latest version is 1.6.3, right? However, I'm installing with aptitude, so I'm getting this apparently older version.

So my problem is:

- I configure 1 LPD printer
- I sent a job with printer door/cover opened, so is not printed right?

But the job stays in the queue with **Spooling job, 0% complete** for infinite minutes.

So, I want to limit this time, for **cups alter status to error (or any other)**, because, if I can change it, and limit the timeout, maybe with some script, I can redirect this job to another printer.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The only timeout that I noticed in looking through the [CUPS documentation](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.4/ref-cupsd-conf.html) that sounded possibly relevant is the option named, `Timeout`. It defaults to 5 minutes (300 seconds) but you can change it to something shorter and see what happens.

```
Timeout 30
```

Be sure to restart CUPS after making any changes to this file.

Comment: Ok, a set the timeout but it didn't work.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel-p4dev - was afraid you'd say that. 8-). I'd scroll through the list of other timeout named options and try those as well.

Comment: I set Timeout = 3. But status keep spooling 0%

Comment: Ok. You know if cups is the better choice for print managment?

Comment: I'll test the `ReloadTimeout`

Comment: @PatrickMaciel-p4dev - I don't know of any other tools, that's what I use at home for my home network and it works well enough.

Comment: For me, works great too. But I need in some cases, redirect the job for other printer. For example: I sent a job for default printer, but has not paper, so I want redirect for a "backup printer".

Comment: You want to do this from CUPS webpage or from the client that sent the print job?

Comment: No, I'll create some script for do that for me, with CUPS api. But first I need be identify every job status.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10595/discussion-between-patrick-maciel-p4dev-and-slm)